# Access to a string member in C++

Tags: c++

When I set `&color` doesn’t works , else without `&` says need a conversion and don’t compile

I want to show the color property in console

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    class Car {
    private:
        int speed;
        string color;

    public:
        Car::Car(int Speed, string Color)
        {
            speed = Speed;
            color = Color;
        }
        void Car::MyMethod()
        {
            cout << color << endl;
        }
    };

    Car Ferrari = Car(200, “Blue”);

    Ferrari.MyMethod();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: You are using the wrong quotes around Blue. It should be `"Blue"` instead of `“Blue”` here are the errors about that: https://ideone.com/NSadxJ

Comment: When dealing with error messages it really helps us if you post the *exact* text of the error as well. "Doesn't compile" is not sufficiently detailed.

Comment: When execute not compile , string it’s not native of c++ and it’s not recognized like type

Comment: In Visual Studio you can easily copy the text of the error messages from the Output tab. And I mean the output tab not the errors list.

Comment: ***string it’s not native of c++ and it’s not recognized like type*** You forgot to include <string> and <iostream>

Comment: All right I’ll write the error

Comment: `Car::Car(int Speed, string Color)` should be `Car(int Speed, string Color)`. When you define the members inside the class you don't use the `Car::` part. Same goes for `Car::MyMethod()`

Comment: I guess the question is abandoned; voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the correct includes, removing scope resolution (`::`) inside the class and fixing the quotation marks the code compiles

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    class Car {
    private:
        int speed;
        string color;

    public:
        Car(int Speed, string Color)
        {
            speed = Speed;
            color = Color;
        }
        void MyMethod()
        {
            cout << color << endl;
        }
    };

    Car Ferrari = Car(200, "Blue");

    Ferrari.MyMethod();

    return 0;
}
```